# how to show tick labels on top of matplotlib plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In matplotlib what is the way to have tick labels both at the bottom and in the top x axis? I have searched a lot and still can't find how to do it.

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410796/turn-off-the-the-upper-right-axis-tick-marks

Comment: @CTZhu, yep I had found it but it seems to be related to changing the position of the xaxis to the top.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sorry, I lied in the comments.  You can do this easily (but it seems to be badly documented)

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(labeltop='on')
```

[image: output]

Comment: Yes this is the best way! I wonder why there are any documentation about it!I link [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992640/vertical-xtick-labels-on-top-not-bottom) too.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with [twiny()](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?highlight=twiny#matplotlib.axes.Axes.twiny):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twiny()
X2tick_location= ax1.xaxis.get_ticklocs() #Get the tick locations in data coordinates as a numpy array
ax2.set_xticks(X2tick_location)
ax2.set_xticklabels(X2tick_location)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Have a look to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514315/how-to-add-a-second-x-axis-in-matplotlib) too for more elaborate plots.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the standard way as of v3.5:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.tick_params('x', top=True, labeltop=True)
```

[image: figure with ticks and labels on top]

Note that the `top` keyword draws the ticks and the `labeltop` keyword draws the labels. Documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tick_params.html).